# eval error in python with trig values

Tags: python, tkinter, eval

I'm designing a calculator in using Tkinter. Before I added trig functions to my code, the eval function worked perfectly fine. However, I discovered that it doesn't work for the trig values that I give it. Am I using the eval function wrong, or does it not work for trig values? The eval function is used in my equalButtonFunction on line 47. If I'm using it wrong, can you tell me how to fix it, or if eval doesn't work for trig, could you recommend an alternative way to do it? Thanks!

```
from __future__ import division
from Tkinter import *
import math

main = Tk()
main.title("Calculator")
main.geometry("375x550")

entry = Text(main)
entry.configure(width=17,height=1)
entry.place(x=13, y=5)
entry.config(font=("Courier", 25))

def oneButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '1')
def twoButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '2')
def threeButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '3')
def fourButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '4')
def fiveButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '5')
def sixButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '6')
def sevenButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '7')
def eightButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '8')
def nineButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '9')
def zeroButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '0')
def addButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '+')
def subButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '-')
def multButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '*')
def divButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '/')
def decimalButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '.')
def equalButtonFunction(event):
    x = entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    entry.delete("1.0", END)
    entry.insert(END, eval(x))#causes error for trig function

def clearButtonFunction(event):
    entry.delete("1.0", END)
def parentheses1ButtonFuction(event):
    entry.insert(END, '(')
def parentheses2ButtonFuction(event):
    entry.insert(END, ')')
def trigButtonFunction(event):
    sinButton.place(x=280, y=50)
    cosButton.place(x=280, y=150)
    tanButton.place(x=280, y=250)
    backButton.place(x=280, y=450)
def sinButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, 'sin(')
def cosButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, 'cos(')
def tanButtonFunction(event):
    entry.insert(END, 'tan(')
def backButtonFunction(event):
    sinButton.place_forget()
    cosButton.place_forget()
    tanButton.place_forget()
    backButton.place_forget()

oneButton = Button(main, text="1", width=10, height=5)
oneButton.place(x=10, y=50)
oneButton.bind('<Button-1>', oneButtonFunction)

twoButton = Button(main, text="2", width=10, height=5)
twoButton.place(x=100, y=50)
twoButton.bind('<Button-1>', twoButtonFunction)

threeButton = Button(main, text="3", width=10, height=5)
threeButton.place(x=190, y=50)
threeButton.bind('<Button-1>', threeButtonFunction)

fourButton = Button(main, text="4", width=10, height=5)
fourButton.place(x=10, y=150)
fourButton.bind('<Button-1>', fourButtonFunction)

fiveButton = Button(main, text="5", width=10, height=5)
fiveButton.place(x=100, y=150)
fiveButton.bind('<Button-1>', fiveButtonFunction)

sixButton = Button(main, text="6", width=10, height=5)
sixButton.place(x=190, y=150)
sixButton.bind('<Button-1>', sixButtonFunction)

sevenButton = Button(main, text="7", width=10, height=5)
sevenButton.place(x=10, y=250)
sevenButton.bind('<Button-1>', sevenButtonFunction)

eightButton = Button(main, text="8", width=10, height=5)
eightButton.place(x=100, y=250)
eightButton.bind('<Button-1>', eightButtonFunction)

nineButton = Button(main, text="9", width=10, height=5)
nineButton.place(x=190, y=250)
nineButton.bind('<Button-1>', nineButtonFunction)

zeroButton = Button(main, text="0", width=10, height=5)
zeroButton.place(x=100, y=350)
zeroButton.bind('<Button-1>', zeroButtonFunction)

decimalButton = Button(main, text=".", width=10, height=5)
decimalButton.place(x=10, y=350)
decimalButton.bind('<Button-1>', decimalButtonFunction)

equalButton = Button(main, text="=", width=10, height=5)
equalButton.place(x=190, y=350)
equalButton.bind('<Button-1>', equalButtonFunction)

addButton = Button(main, text="+", width=10, height=5)
addButton.place(x=280, y=50)
addButton.bind('<Button-1>', addButtonFunction)

subButton = Button(main, text="-", width=10, height=5)
subButton.place(x=280, y=150)
subButton.bind('<Button-1>', subButtonFunction)

multButton = Button(main, text="X", width=10, height=5)
multButton.place(x=280, y=250)
multButton.bind('<Button-1>', multButtonFunction)

divButton = Button(main, text="/", width=10, height=5)
divButton.place(x=280, y=350)
divButton.bind('<Button-1>', divButtonFunction)

clearButton = Button(main, text="Clear", width=10, height=5)
clearButton.place(x=10, y=450)
clearButton.bind('<Button-1>', clearButtonFunction)

parentheses1Button = Button(main, text="(", width=10, height=5)
parentheses1Button.place(x=100, y=450)
parentheses1Button.bind('<Button-1>', parentheses1ButtonFuction)

parentheses2Button = Button(main, text=")", width=10, height=5)
parentheses2Button.place(x=190, y=450)
parentheses2Button.bind('<Button-1>', parentheses2ButtonFuction)

trigButton = Button(main, text="Trig", width=10, height=5)
trigButton.place(x=280, y=450)
trigButton.bind('<Button-1>', trigButtonFunction)

sinButton = Button(main, text="Sin", width=10, height=5)
sinButton.bind('<Button-1>', sinButtonFunction)

cosButton = Button(main, text="Cos", width=10, height=5)
cosButton.bind('<Button-1>', cosButtonFunction)

tanButton = Button(main, text="Tan", width=10, height=5)
tanButton.bind('<Button-1>', tanButtonFunction)

backButton = Button(main, text="Back", width=10, height=5)
backButton.bind('<Button-1>', backButtonFunction)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's `x` content (the text that `eval` fails to evaluate)?

Comment: `cos()` isn't a defined method.... `math.cos()` is

Comment: You said `eval` doesn't work for trig functions. What's not working about it?
 Is there an error message you can share with us?

Answer (score 1):

```
def cos(x): 
    return math.cos(x)
def sin(x): 
    return math.sin(x)
def tan(x): 
    return math.tan(x)
```

or as Eric mentions

```
from math import sin, cos, tan
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the functions with trignometric identitites such as:  `entry.insert(END, 'tan(')`
with: `entry.insert(END, 'math.tan(')`

and it should work fine.

Replacing it with `'numpy.tan('` will also fix your problem if you have array or matrix of values.

Answer (score 1):

You can import numpy or math or any library that has trig. As this

```
   from numpy import sin, cos, tan, cosh, tanh, sinh
```

Answer (score 1):

For trigonometry, import the math module and when using `eval()`, place `math.cos()` or whatever type of trigonometry equation you want.

Example:

```
import math
print(eval("math.cos(1)"))
```